# Bulk export of data from multiple table from mysql database

Tags: mysql, export, bulk-load

I need to export 100's of rows from different table in to a csv file. I have tried by exporting it but am getting memory limit exceeds error. Also I have Changed the limit in ini file but i couldn't proceed further. Please post the solution if any.
Thanks.

Comment: You need to provide more information such as how you're trying to export, what you're expecting as output and your configurations

Comment: $SelectValue = "SELECT * FROM ".$table."";
$values = mysqli_query($link,$SelectValue);
$getnumRows = mysqli_num_rows($values);
while ($rowr = mysqli_fetch_row($values)) {
 for ($j=0;$j<$i;$j++) {
      $csv_output .= $rowr[$j].", ";
 }
   $csv_output .= "\ 
 ";    }
$file = 'export';
$filename = $file."_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time());
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header("Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");
print $csv_output;   
exit;                     This is the scrip am using.

Comment: I have changed the memory limit from 126m to 260 and tried. Exact output is to export 200  records from more than 500 table in to a single csv file.

Comment: include it in your question